# how to get 10th grouping value in sed?

Tags: unix, sed

It is my sed.

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)\([0-9]\)\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)\([0-9]\)\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)\([0-9]\)\([a-z]\)/\10/g'
```

I tried to get 10th grouping value.But,It gives first grouping value with 0(zero).

How to get 10th grouping value?

whether it is possible to get the 10th grouping value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` only supports 10 groups(from `\0` to `\9`), and doesn't support non-captured group.

You can rewrite you command as:

```
sed 's/[a-z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][0-9]\([a-z]\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: @ kev , Thank you.. \1 is used to get the first group values.what is the use of \0? which scenario i have to use \0? can you give some guideline for that.

Comment: You can try `python`. It has `named-group`. Regexp is much clear when groups have names.

Comment: In some sed's `\0` is an alias for `&` i.e. the whole of the LHS matching pattern.