# Reference 10th submatch

Tags: regex, sed

Normally when you call sed, you can call `\1` to reference the submatch number one, i.e.:

```
<something> | sed "s/<regex>\(<regex>\)<regex>/\1/"
```

This will just take the middle regex and remove the outer ones.

But what do you do, if you have more then 9 matches? Simply writing `\10` doesn't work, because it will be interpreted as `take submatch number one and add a zero behind it`.

Comment: Can you simplify it to reduce the number of capturing groups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible in sed.  You'll have to use a different tool.

Here are similar questions on SO:

[Circumvent the sed backreference limit \1 through \9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318114/circumvent-the-sed-backreference-limit-1-through-9).

[how to get 10th grouping value in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992650/how-to-get-10th-grouping-value-in-sed)

Comment: thanks, the first one actually says (which I can only test tomorrow) that you can use perl instead of sed and apply a "s/in/out/" expression nearly in the same fashion but much more powerful. That is actually quite, quite helpful! So I voted for duplicate of your first link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about SED, but in many languages (javascript, ruby), that have regex implementations that allow for submatching (or backreferencing as it is sometimes called), only support `\1` through `\9`. `\10` is simply not allowed.

Any additional backreferencing would require the use of a more sophisticated parser.

Comment: I think Perl allows it, though.

Comment: Some regex implementations, such as Python, _will_ accept `\10`, etc, _if_ there are more than 9 capture groups in the pattern.