# Converting sed cmd line to script

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix, sed

If I have the line

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^,]*), *([^,]*), *([^,]*), *([^.]*), *([^,]*) *([^,]), ([^ ]*) *([^,]) *([^,])/\2, \1, \3, ``\4," \\emph{\5} \\textbf{\8},{\9} (\6)  /'
```

and I want to put it into a script called (Script.txt) how do I do that so I can run it against file.txt like this:

```
sed -f script.txt file.txt
```

Comment: just put the content of the single quotes into the file, from the `s/` upt the last `/`

Comment: ... and use `sed -E -f script.txt file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks!  also, anyway you can use more than 9 groups if you use this script form?

Comment: @user: [It's not possible in sed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11833409/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 's/([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^,]*), *([^,]*), *([^,]*), *([^.]*), *([^,]*) *([^,]), ([^ ]*) *([^,]) *([^,])/\2, \1, \3, ``\4," \\emph{\5} \\textbf{\8},{\9} (\6)  /' > script.txt
sed -E -f script.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! also, anyway you can use more than 9 groups if you use this script form?